Moving from Rabbit Client Lib to Masstransit Lib
Moving on from the RabbitMQ C# library, there is a question about MassTransit that I am not quite understanding.
When I use the RabbitMQ library and send a message to a queue, by default it uses Exchange: (AMQP default), to avoid an exchange for each queue, how to archive the same effect with MassTransit, which means sending a message to a queue without specifying an exchange so that it can be routed through Exchange: (AMQP default)

MassTransit has supported RabbitMQ for over a decade, and adopted a very specific topology from the start to ensure the greatest flexibility in how applications work with RabbitMQ.
MassTransit always creates a matching exchange with the same name as the queue, to make it easy to directly send to a queue using that exchange. It's also to support capabilities such as wire tapping to store copies of messages delivered to a queue for troubleshooting and/or auditing.
I cover this in the details video as well, and explain the reasons behind the way MassTransit works.

Thanks for your response, and great video! We're using MassTransit to stay broker-agnostic and avoid reinventing the wheel with a custom solution. However, it's essential that we don't change anything in our current deployment.
Queues follow this structure: queuename, queuename.deadletter, queuename.error.
Exchanges are used in a JMS Topic style, configured as fanout, and bind to either none or at least one queue.
Given that topology how to archive the same with MassTransit using the Default Exchange

If you need guidance on how to migrate to MassTransit and keep your existing structure (or closely replicate it), you can book an architecture engagement to get advice specific to your scenario. Email support@masstransit.io to get details on how to set it up.
